# How to get back the value of an elevation request

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I face some problems to get back the elevation value from a function. I'm not able to get that value. Would be great if somebody has a solution for that.
Here is my code:

```
function getElevation(latLng) {
  seaLevel = 'Error';
  var locations = [];
  locations.push(latLng);
  //Create a LocationElevationRequest object using the array[0] value
  var positionalRequest = {
    'locations': locations
  }
  //Initiate the location request
  elevationService.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
      // Retrieve the first result
      if (results[0]) {
        var seaLvl = parseFloat(results[0].elevation.toFixed(1));
      }
      dropElevation(seaLvl);
    }
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = seaLevel;
  });
  function dropElevation(tmpLevel) {
    //alert(tmpLevel); at this point the value is correct
    seaLevel = tmpLevel;
  }
  return seaLevel; //at this point the value is always as defined above
} //End function (getElevation)
```

The call of it looks like this:

```
var seaLvl = getElevation(latLng);
```

Thanks in advance to show me what I'm doing wrong
Guido

Answer (score 0):

The elevations service is asynchronous.  You must use the value inside the callback routine.  Something like this:

```
elevationService.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status)  
{
  if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
    // Retrieve the first result
    if (results[0]) {
      var seaLvl = parseFloat(results[0].elevation.toFixed(1));
      dropElevation(seaLvl);
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = seaLevel;
    } else {
      alert("no result");
    }
   }
 });
```

And something like this:

```
var seaLvl = getElevation(latLng);
```

won't work (the value is not available until the message returns from the server).